# Disabling GSSAuthentication in sshd_conf has no effect

Tags: ssh, rocky-linux

I'm using a fresh install of the most recent build of `RockyLinux 9`. I'm trying to disable GSSAPI for SSH based login, along with passwords and permit only public key based login. Setting `GSSAPIAuthentication no` in `sshd_conf` doesn't appear to actually disable it, based on the output from the ssh client prompt. Are there any other configuration parameters necessary?

```
$ grep -i gss /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# GSSAPI options
GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPIEnablek5users no

# service sshd restart

#on an another host
$ ssh test@1.2.3.4
test@1.2.3.4: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

Comment: What do you have in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d? 50-redhat.conf seems to enable it and it is included early on. As far as I remember the first occurence in sshd_config  wins.

Comment: I haven't used a redhat based system in some time this must be a new thing. But setting `GSSAPIAuthentication no` in `50-redhat.conf` fixed the problem. If you put this in an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you have in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d? 50-redhat.conf seems to enable it and it is included early on. As far as I remember the first occurrence in sshd_config wins.

Following on the comment: please have a look at `Include` config directive for both ssh_config and sshd_config. It's been there since at least RHEL 8 for ssh_config and was introduced in RHEL 9 for sshd_config.